# Combine 2 columns to key/value array

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

My answer should be simple, but I tried many things and coudn't get the expected result. I Have 3 columns in AWS Glue.

```
identifier  brand_key   brand_value
1           1324        Brand 1
1           64          Brand 2
1           262         Brand 3
1           457822      Brand 4
1           343         Brand 5
1           23          Brand 6
1           53          Brand 7
1           6           Brand 8
1           32          Brand 9
1           463464      Brand 10
1           456         Brand 11
```

It contains 3 columns, identifier, the brand_key and brand_value.
THe identifier I added only to group on it. Does not have a extra function.
Now I tried many things and this is the closest I could get.

code:

```
newdf1 = newdf1.groupBy('identifier').agg( collect_set('brand_key').alias('brands') )
```

result:

```
[
  {
    "brands": [
      "Brand 1", 
      "Brand 2", 
      "Brand 3", 
      "Brand 4", 
      "Brand 5", 
      "Brand 6", 
      "Brand 7", 
      "Brand 8", 
      "Brand 9", 
      "Brand 10", 
      "Brand 11", 
    ]
  }
]
```

But I try to get this output:

```
[
  {
    "brands": {
      "1324": "Brand 1", 
      "64": "Brand 2", 
      "262": "Brand 3", 
      "457822": "Brand 4", 
      "343": "Brand 5", 
      "23": "Brand 6", 
      "53": "Brand 7", 
      "6": "Brand 8", 
      "32": "Brand 9", 
      "463464": "Brand 10"
      "456": "Brand 11"
    }
  }
]
```

It should not be difficult right? I also tried to create a JSON field with:

```
newdf1 = newdf1.withColumn("combined",concat(lit("{\""),'brand_value',lit("\":\""),'brand_key',lit("\"}")))
```

And then convert that back to columns, but also was not working like expected.

Comment: Is the expected result grouped by identifier and spliced into the target json string?

Comment: This is the expected result:

`
[
  {
    "brands": {
      "1324": "Brand 1", 
      "64": "Brand 2", 
      "262": "Brand 3", 
      "457822": "Brand 4", 
      "343": "Brand 5", 
      "23": "Brand 6", 
      "53": "Brand 7", 
      "6": "Brand 8", 
      "32": "Brand 9", 
      "463464": "Brand 10"
      "456": "Brand 11"
    }
  }
]`

Comment: Can you try creating dictionary out of these 2 columns as key, value pairs, if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dataframe has registered as a temporary view named `tmp`, use spark SQL to concatenate strings.

```
......
sql = """
    select
        concat('[{"brands": {',concat_ws(',',collect_list(concat('"',brand_key,'": "',brand_value,'"'))),'}}]') result
    from tmp
    group by identifier
"""
df = spark.sql(sql)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: I tried to do it like this. Unfortunately AWS Glue doesn't like already formatted JSON in the input when running the pipeline. It will escape this:

`
[
  {
    "result": "[{\"brands\": {\"1324\": \"Brand 1\",\"64\": \"Brand 2\",\"262\": \"Brand 3\" ...
  }
]
`